# ModuleNotFoundException after Thorntail upgrade

Tags: wildfly, thorntail, jboss-modules

I just upgraded the Thorntail version of my application from 2.5.0.Final to 2.6.0. Final. 
My app is using a module (for authorization), which lies in a separate git repo, so I've included it in my pom.xml.

Since the upgrade I'm getting a ModuleNotFoundException when the module is called (authorization is triggered)

```
Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: org.apache.santuario.xmlsec
at org.jboss.modules.Module.addPaths(Module.java:1266) [backend-thorntail.jar:]
at org.jboss.modules.Module.link(Module.java:1622) [backend-thorntail.jar:]
at org.jboss.modules.Module.relinkIfNecessary(Module.java:1650) [backend-thorntail.jar:]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModule(ModuleLoader.java:299) [backend-thorntail.jar:]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModule(ModuleLoader.java:283) [backend-thorntail.jar:]
at org.jboss.as.security.plugins.SecurityActions.getModuleClassLoader(SecurityActions.java:50) [thorntailwildfly-security-18.0.1.Final5333088777079625058.jar:18.0.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.security.plugins.ModuleClassLoaderLocator.get(ModuleClassLoaderLocator.java:65) [thorntailwildfly-security-18.0.1.Final5333088777079625058.jar:18.0.1.Final]
... 49 more
```

The problem is, that the *org.apache.santuario.xmlsec* dependency of the module is not being bundled in the thorntail jar, while all other dependencies are present in the jar.

This is the module.xml of the used module:

```
</module>
    ...
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.servlet.api"/>
        <module name="org.apache.xalan"/>
        <module name="org.apache.santuario.xmlsec"/>
        <module name="org.picketbox"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.logging"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

Does anyone have an idea how I can "force" Thorntail to include this dependency?
I also tried simply adding the latest version of the missing dependency in my pom.xml but unfortunately this doesn't help.

Any help is appreciated - thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to check if wildfly modules directory contains this module artifact ? If so you can also try to add it on you jboss-deployment-structure. xml  so that it is available on an application path

Comment: @FholisaniMashegana Mashegana what do you mean by wildfly modules directory?
The Thorntail Runner and/or the thorntail-maven-plugin should bundle all needed dependencies in the resulting fat jar.

Comment: As a temporary fix, I had to create a folder "modules.org.apache.santuario.xmlsec.main" in my resources folder. Inside that folder I added a module.xml file that contains the xmlsec dependency as artifact. However I also had to include **all 'recursive'** transitive dependencies as artifacts, so clearly this cannot be the way this should be fixed...